# Filtering flask parameters through HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I am attempting to display a selection of rows from an sql table that is passed to my webpage through flask. Which rows are selected depends on a value that is selected from an HTML dropdown list (one of the columns in the table is `id`. I need the rows whose id corresponds to the selected value from the form):

```
<form name="dropdownForm" style="padding:10px 0px 0px 20px" onchange="calldropdown(this.value)">
    <select name="dropdownselection" id='dropdownresult'>
        <option value=1>Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>Option 3</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

At the moment, I am passing the result from this form to a javascript function, but so far, have only been able to display the selected value from the form, instead of what I need:

```
<p id = areatodisplay"></p>
function calldropdown(dropdownresult) {
    var result= document.getElementById('dropdownresult').value
    document.getElementById("areatodiaplsy").innerHTML = result;
}
```

I need some help with where to go from here though - is what I want even feasible? I need the displayed data to change whenever the a new selection is made in the dropdown list, without the page refreshing - hence the javascript.

I have attempted to use jinja tags in my javascript function as part of the `innerHTML`line, resulting in syntax errors:

`document.getElementById("areatodiaplsy").innerHTML = {% for i in getInfo %} {% if i.id == result %} {{i.name}} {% endif %} {% endfor %};`

For completeness, the flask code I am using:

```
@app.route('/live')
def live():
    return render_template('live.html', getInfo=Info.query.all())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        function calldropdown(dropdownresult) {
             document.getElementById("areatodisplay").innerHTML = dropdownresult;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="dropdownselection" id='dropdownresult' onchange="calldropdown(this.value)">
    <option value=1>Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>Option 3</option>
</select>

<p id="areatodisplay"></p>

</body>
</html>
```